# Load data from database on new page, according to what button was pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, servlets

Part of my index.html contains 3 buttons-anchors like this (There is some bootstrap as well)

**Index.html**

```html
<a id="category1" href="html/auctionBay.html" class="portfolio-link" >
<a id="category2" href="html/auctionBay.html" class="portfolio-link" >
<a id="category3" href="html/auctionBay.html" class="portfolio-link" >
```

These buttons redirect me to the auctionBay.html which contains a div
**auctionBay.html**

```html
<div id="result" class="container"></div>
```

What i need, is when i press a button from the above, to go to the auctionBay.html and accordingly to what was pressed, print the data from the appropriate table (category1-3) from my database into the 'result' div (it's important to be in the div). 
I currently have a servlet that can do this statically when auction.html loads using an ajax call

```
        var j = jQuery.noConflict();
    function myFunction() {
        j.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : '../auctionsDisplay',
            success : function(data) {
                j("#result").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

but only works if i specify the category manually.(antiques=category1 for example)

AuctionDisplay.java

```
public class AuctionsDisplay extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String result = "";

    try {
        Connection con = DBConnection.getCon();
        String category = "antiques";
        String query = "select id, name, price from " + category;
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        int i;
        result = "";
        boolean flag = rs.next();
        while (flag) {
            result += "<div class='container'><div class='row'><h1 id='antiques' class='category'>Antiques</h1></div><div class='row'>";
            i = 0;
            while (i < 4 && flag) {
                ps = con.prepareStatement("select highestBidder, ends from auctions where itemId=?");
                ps.setString(1, rs.getString("id"));

                ResultSet rs2 = ps.executeQuery();
                rs2.next();
                String price = rs.getString("price");
                if (rs2.getString("highestBidder") != null)
                    price = rs2.getString("highestBidder");

                result += "<div class='col-md-3' portfolio-item>";
                result += "<div class='w3-container w3-hover-shadow w3-center'>" + "<h2>" + rs.getString("name")
                        + "</h2><div class='w3-card-20' style='width:100%'>"
                        + "<input id='2' type='image' src='../img/portfolio/w3.jpg' data-toggle='modal' "
                        + "data-target='#MoreInfo'style='width:90%;'>"
                        + "<div class='w3-container w3-center responsive'>"
                        + "<p style='padding:5px;'>Highest Bid: " + price + "\u20ac <br> " + "Ends at: "
                        + rs2.getString("ends") + "<p></div></div></div></div>";

                flag = rs.next();
                i++;

            }

            result += "</div></div>";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    out.println(result);

}
```

I understand jquery, ajax, get-post requests, javascript (no php please), so how can i achieve what i want ? It's propably simple but it's confusing me

Comment: use url query params just like any other GET

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want in javascript thanks to `window.LocalStorage`. Since you want your data from one page to be sent to another page(where the browser loads a whole new page which results in the loss of any data retrieved by the last page), via javascript you **WILL** need to make use of localStorage to get the desired results.

**How to?**

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
function myFunction(category_id) {
    //use this id to fetch your appropriate data 
    j.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : '../auctionsDisplay',
        success : function(data) {
            localStorage.setItem("category_result", data);
        }
    });
}

j('.portfolio-link').click(function(){
    var category_id = this.id //this will give you the pressed <a>'s ID value
    myFunction(category_id);
})

//then on document load retrieve the localStorage value you stored.
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (localStorage.getItem("category_result") !== null) {
        //feed the value to the 'results' div
        j('#result').html(localStorage.getItem("category_result"));
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helped

Comment: This is not exactly what i wanted, but the localStorage tip helped me to solve my issue. What i needed was index.html to save the category in local storage and then auction.html retrieve it and make the ajax call. Thanks for the help though